# Python CAN receiving data (pdo mapping)

Tags: python, can-bus, canopen

I am currently working on making a CAN tracer with Python. The connection as well as the received data from CAN work. My question now is: how can I change the PDO mapping and stop and start the transmission via CAN like it works with CANopen?

```
import canopen

# CAN Setting
can_interface = '0'

can_filters = [{"can_id":0x018A, "can_mask": 0xFFFF, "extended": True}]

bus = can.interface.Bus(can_interface, bustype='ixxat',can_filters=can_filters)

while True:
     message = bus.recv()
     print(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be in pre operational mode and send SDO request to change PDO mapping.

You can get these information in the documentation or in the EDS file.

If doing modification do not forget to send the save SDO request at the end else the node will restart with its default value